# Css vertical div fill up but not overflow?

Tags: html, css

```
<div id="main" style="overflow:hidden;height:80%;>
    <div id="header">
    </div>
    <div id="content" style="overflow:hidden;">
    </div>
</div>
```

I have two divs in the main div, and I want the content div to fill up the remainder of the main div, but if stuff fills up the content div past its filled up height, I don't want the content div to grow any taller.

I've seen some other stackoverflow questions like this, but none of the answers have worked for me. Tried: [Make DIV fill remainder of page vertically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2898221/make-div-fill-remainder-of-page-vertically), [Get CSS Div to fill available height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2297453/get-css-div-to-fill-available-height), and [How to make a DIV fill the remaining vertical space of the browser window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4980308/how-to-make-a-div-fill-the-remaining-vertical-space-of-the-browser-window)

I think the main difference is that I require the content div to fill up, but ALSO not overflow.  Is this possible with only css?

Update:
I kept trying out different pieces of code and this is what I want: http://jsfiddle.net/zXnnp/.  But for some reason I couldn't replicate it on my localhost.  And then I found out it was because I was using http://jamesflorentino.github.io/nanoScrollerJS/ And for some reason class="nano" on the content div messed things up.  Still investigating on what's wrong.

Update2:
class="nano" has height:100%; so I just overrode it with height:auto; and things are now fine.  Thanks for all the help!

Comment: should be possible. What have you tried? Can we see some css? a fiddle perhaps?

Comment: Please use http://jsbin.com to share an example of your code and write a follow-up comment for us to notice the update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
/* stretch the body to full height */
body, html {
    height: 100%;
}

/* stretching the containers */
#header {
     height: 50px; /* just a random number i chose, not sure what you wanted here */   
}
#content {
    height: 100%;
    margin-bottom: -50px; /* same as the header height, but negative */
}
```

You can see the code in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/mRK24/

The magic lies in first stretching you body to viewport height. The #main will then become 80% of the viewport height. Next you give the header some fixed height, and the content you set to a height of 100%, with a negative margin bottom that is the same as the height of the header.

Note that some of your content will be lost, due to the `overflow:hidden;`. Strange, cause you can not know how much since you don't know the height of your user's viewport. Perhaps you should consider setting the overflow of the content to scroll, cause I can't imagine you would want part of you content to be invisible.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the CSS property max-height? This is from CSS 2 and should not have any compatability issues.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_max-height.asp

If you post some editable code then we could play with it and help you find some ways of making it work.

Comment: since the main div height is 80%, and the header div, if known, will be of a constant height, how can I know what to set the max-height of the content to without calculating it in js?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you're after, but maybe this will get you close:

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/TCVvn/1

```
#main {
    height: 80%;
    width: 80%;
    position: absolute;
}
#header {
    height: 50px;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
}
#content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 70px;
    right: 5px;
    left: 5px;
    bottom: 5px;
    overflow: auto;
}

<div id="main">
    <div id="header">Header</div>
    <div id="content">Content</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep `overflow:hidden` on `<div id="#main">` and let the content div take as much height as it wants with no overflow restrictions. `#main` will cut off `#content` if it gets too tall to fit inside of `#main`.